# Trying to build upvote system in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am trying to build an `upvote system in cakephp` but I am having some trouble and am ending up with unidentified index errors and array to string conversion.

This is my function in my `PostsController`:

```
public function like ($id=null, $like=NULL) {
    if(!$id) {throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $post = $this -> Post-> findById($id);
    $like = $this->Like->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('username' =>
            array($this->Auth->user('username')))
    ));
    if(!$post) {throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this -> set('post',$post);
    $this -> set('like', $like);
    if ($like['Like']['username'] == $post['Post']['username'] && $like['Like']['article_id'] == $post['Post']['id']){
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    else{
        $this->Like->saveField('username', $this->Auth->user('username'));
        $this->Like->saveField('article_id', $post);
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

}
```

At the top of my controller I do `var $uses = array('Post','Like');` So my `PostsController` knows to use the `Like` model too. Now I know what problem is, I just don't know how to fix it. When I set the fields, username gets set in the DB, but `$post` returns an array of all posts. What I want to happen is for it to only return the current post I am on. This is what I am doing in my view:

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->link(
                        'Like',
                        array('action'=>'Like',$post['Post']['id']));
     ?>
```

And this is the action that goes with that view:

```
        public function view ($id=null) {
if(!$id) {throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
}
$post = $this -> Post-> findById($id);
if(!$post) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
}
$this -> set('post',$post);
}
```

How can I get my link function to only return the current post I want to like and not an array of all the posts?

EDIT - Forgot to mention I'm getting an `Undefined index:  Like` error on the 13th line of my posts controller.

Comment: It's not clear in which action your problem is and what should happen.

Comment: Sorry, the issue in the `like` action. I tooled around with it more and just go it to only throw a Undefined Index error on line 13 of the action. That's my issue right now.

Comment: As for what I want to happen: I have two fields in a table (likes) and I want to put the current user in username field and the post_id of the current post I am "liking" into my article_id field.  @cornelb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
$like = $this->Like->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('username' =>
        array($this->Auth->user('username')))
));
```

This will give an array with more items, so you cannot use `$like['Like']`. This is why you are getting the warning.

You could use `$like[0]['Like']`.

If you need to go through each of the likes, you can do

```
foreach ($like as $currentLike) {
     if ($currentLike['Like']['username'] == $post['Post']['username'] ....
}
```

Please include more details about why you are making these comparisons and redirects, and maybe more of the code can be refactored.

Comment: yeah I was exhausted when I wrote this question. I ended up figuring it all out. I was just trying to build a feature where users can like posts. So an user can like many posts and a post can be liked by many users. I'll post more later when I have the code in front of me. @cornelb